# Oracle SOA Suite in a nutshell

Tags: oracle, architecture, apache-camel, weblogic, oracle-soa

I need laconic explanation of what **Oracle SOA Suite 12c** is and what are its *technical* core functionalities. Oracle's web page just uses a lot of buzzwords and states it can be used for integration with cloud, mobile dives and IoT.

Why should I choose Oracle SOA Suite over Oracle WebLogic and Apache Camel, or other integration framework?

Comment: To be honest, having spoken to people who have used it, I cannot give you a single reason why you should use Oracle SOA Suite ;)

Comment: What are your initial requirements and what made you look at Oracle SOA Suite?

Answer (score 2):

I won't go into a long-winded reply, but I think the more technical bits and reasons for using it can be found on [Oracle's documentation site](https://docs.oracle.com), specifically [Oracle SOA Suite](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/soasuite/index.html).  Most of the stuff under "Understanding Oracle SOA Suite" probably provide more than enough information to give you an idea.  It's not going to be a short read, however.

Additionally, you'll see the "Books" section on the left shows a list of all the documentation tied to or associated with SOA Suite, and this one in particular might give you a good idea where SOA Suite fits, what they built it to do (and for whom they built it for):

- [Fusion Middleware Understanding Oracle SOA Suite](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/soasuite/concepts/toc.htm)